# Should we protected a question just because one person added a low-quality answer late?

Tags: discussion, protected-questions

I am referring specifically to this question:

[What is the word for an image hidden inside a painting?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32021/what-is-the-word-for-an-image-hidden-inside-a-painting)

Five hours ago someone left what I consider a particularly bad answer.  Five hours ago, this question was protected by a moderator.  I'm not sure how this helps the situation.

It seems to me, this action prevents someone from leaving a better answer in the future, doesn't remove the bad answer, and adds a big bar to the question, taking up real estate on the page.

So what is the upside to this?  Or is this a poor practice?

Comment: That answer might get deleted in due time by the moderators since it is of exceptionally low quality.

Comment: It's a good idea to link to the answer as well as the question (use the "Share" link/button to get a URL) so others know exactly what you're referring to without having to do time calculations.

Comment: What are the properties of 'protected' vs 'locked' vs 'closed'? Protection stops answers by low rep users, (who presumably are more likely to give crap answers), that's all.

Answer (score 7):

The question has been up for almost two years. It has three upvoted answers. Two of the three seem rather thorough. One of the three is accepted. The OP is satisfied with what he has.

The question also has not one, but *three* downvoted answers by one-rep users. We cannot keep babysitting it like that.

A reputation of 10 is hardly "a big bar". In fact it's the smallest possible bar: just one upvote on an answer elsewhere. And we have literally hundreds of accounts that prove how easy it is to get 10 reps or more simply for posting the most inane one-liner question. And if you come from a different SE site, no matter what its topic, you get an association bonus that is ten times as high.

As to deleting a poor answer, that is completely orthogonal to protecting a question. The two actions are not connected, by design. (After all, the new user should *see* what kind of reaction what kind of answer gets him.)

Comment: The association bonus that you get from coming from another site does not allow you to post answers to protected questions. You must receive the necessary rep on that particular site. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/106745